# How to set dropdown values from json data using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have succesfully setup the option in both dropdowns.

In my database Parent name is Sally and child name is SallyChild2,when an updating a parent and child name of this page i need to populate the entire data with select this particular parent name as Sally and childname as SallyChild2

But my requirement is initially i need Parent as Sally and child as SallyChild2 is selected,and it should SallyChild remaining

My database value is Parent - Sally
Child - SallyChild2
So I hard coded as this wat but not working

```
$scope.selectedParent="Sally";
$scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";
```

But its not working

This is my script.js

script.js

```
var app=angular.module('TestApp', ['angular.filter','ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('category',
    {
        views : {   
            "body" :
        {
            url : '/category',
            templateUrl : 'category.html',
            controller : 'TestController'
        }
        }   

    })

    .state('category.subcategory',
    {
    url : '/subcategory',
    views : {                              
        "subbody@category" :
        {
        templateUrl : 'sample.html',
        controller : 'SampleController'              
        }
    }
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is MainController")

    $scope.getCategory=function()
    {
        $state.go('category');
    }


}

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

//TestController.$inject['dataservice'];

function TestController($scope, $state){


    $scope.data=[
     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "George Child1"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild1"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "Sally Child1"          
     },

     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "GeorgChild2"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild2"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "Infant Food"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "SallyChild2"          
     }
    ];

    $scope.selectedParent="Sally";
    $scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";

    function onParentChange(parent){
      if(!parent){
    $scope.child = undefined;
      }
    }


    $scope.getValue=function()
    {
    alert("Call to Sample Controller")

    var currentState = $state.current.name;
    var targetState = 'category.subcategory';

    if(currentState === targetState)
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    else
        $state.go(targetState);
    $state.go(".subcategory");

    //$state.go('category.subcategory');
    }
}


app.controller('SampleController', SampleController);

function SampleController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is SampleController")

}
```

category.html

```
  <div>    
    <hr>

    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Parent</b></label>
      <select ng-model="selectedParent"
        ng-init="selectedParent = null"
        ng-change="onParentChange(selectedParent)"
        class="form-control" id="data">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parentName'">{{key}}</option>           
      </select>
    </div>              
      </form>  
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-3">      
      <form>    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Child Names</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="child" 
        ng-disabled="!selectedParent"
        ng-options="data.childName for data in data| filter: {parentName:selectedParent} | removeWith:{childName : 'Infant Food'}" ng-change="getValue()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>          

      </form>     
  </div>
    <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more clear of the sentence- _But my requirement is initially i need Parent as Sally and child as SallyChild2 is selected,and it should SallyChild remaining_

Comment: What you're looking for is ng-options : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @Mateen Momin In my database Parent name is Sally and child name is SallyChild2,when an updating a parent and child name of this page i need to populate the entire data with select this particular parent name as Sally and childname as SallyChild2.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2JWb2/5/

Comment: @ LoremIpsum I couldnt get it